# Using Drive.Properties.update to update or add a file property

Tags: google-apps-script

I have enabled the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) in an apps script. For a file in Google Drive, I need to set metadata properties that may already exist, so I am trying to use the `update` method of `Drive.Properties`. This method is supposed to "Update a property or add it if it doesn't exist." (See [Properties: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/update).)

The following code fails silently (with nothing logged to the Logger and no properties added to the file). However, if I step through these same lines, I do see the catch block executed every time.

```
var fileId = '1jgoihblahblahblah' /* an existing file id */;
var property = {key: 'TestKey', value: 'TestValue', visibility: 'PUBLIC'}
try {
  Drive.Properties.update(property, fileId, "TestKey");
} catch (e) {
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

If I replace the call to `update` with this line:

```
Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
```

... then the code works every time. The properties are written and are returned by calling `Drive.Properties.list(fileId)`.

<s>Testing the same values using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/update) (with real values or the "TestKey" and "TestValue" examples above) always works correctly, so I don't think it's simply a matter of providing bad data.</s> **UPDATE:** The API explorer is now returning an error "Property keys may only contain letters, numbers, and the characters .!@$%^&*()-_/" no matter what values I pass in. However, there are obviously no invalid characters in key names like "TestKey" and "Link" (which is one of the actual keys I am using).

1) How can I troubleshoot the error from within the Script editor? I can't yet figure out how to retrieve the error text, since `update` fails silently even without the try/catch.

2) I am using the syntax specified by the autocomplete prompt, since there's not actually any documentation for Apps Script syntax for advanced service.

[image: Autocomplete Syntax]

Is that syntax correct? If so, am I doing something wrong that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is irrelevant because despite its name, `Drive.Properties.insert` does the same thing.

See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759642